# Parsing json with $.parseJSON

Tags: jquery, json, console

I have a json data which looks something like this

```
[{"id":"1","name":"Muslin","image1":"muslin.jpg"},{"id":"72","name":"Gagra choli","image1":"gagra choli.jpg"},{"id":"73","name":"Lahenga saree","image1":"lahenga saree.jpg"},{"id":"74","name":"Ao dai","image1":"Ao dai.jpg"},{"id":"75","name":"Brocade","image1":"brocade.jpg"},{"id":"77","name":"Button","image1":"button.jpg"},{"id":"78","name":"Bathrobe","image1":"Bathrobe.jpg"},{"id":"79","name":"Bathtowel","image1":"Bathtowel.jpg"},{"id":"80","name":"Cassock","image1":"cassock.jpg"},{"id":"81","name":"Shirt","image1":"shirt.jpg"},{"id":"82","name":"Dolce and Gabanna","image1":"dolce_and_gabanna.jpg"},{"id":"83","name":"asasa","image1":"1009578_1392050054339713_1292927121_o.jpg"},{"id":"84","name":"knbdfjhbjhbvjh","image1":"images_(1)10.jpg"}]
```

now i used some code like this

```
var obj=$.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(res));
                $('#response').html(obj.id);
```

But the console says that the `obj.id` is undefined

Comment: What is the `res` variable? I suspect you're going about this incorrectly.

Comment: you can access id as obj[0].id not obj.id

Comment: There are lots of IDs in that array, which one do you want to put in the HTML?

Comment: aaise hi bhai, wo bhi sahi hai

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var obj` is an array of objects. so you need to use index .

```
$('#response').html(obj[0].id);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var obj=$.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(res));
```

You stringify an object to a string, and then parse it back to object. Why not just use the `res` directly?

`res` is an array, if you want to get the id, then you have to use the index.

For example:

```
$('#response').html(res[0].id);
```